# switch duplicates packets and forward in two route

Tags: switch, duplicate-ip

there is a network including a router, two hosts and a switch which connects hosts to router. i have a virtual machine on my system. the network adapter is set to act as bridge. so the virtual machine and real OS are my 2 hosts on different LAN. they use one network card and are connected to a switch.
when each of host send a packet to the other one, the switch duplicate the packet and forward it to both router and the other host.
how can I solve the duplicate packet problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question needs some clarification. How many physical hosts are connected to the switch? 1 or 2? What hypervisor are you running?

Comment: there is only one physical host connected to switch. my pc and the VM on it, are two host connected to each other using a router.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you put a NIC into bridged mode it acts as a layer 2 switch. If both hosts are on separate subnets, then there is no way for them to communicate between them without a router or layer 3 switch.

If this isn't the case, then please provide which hypervisor you are running, and how many physical hosts are connected as your question is worded funny. I will update the answer.

Comment: there is only one physical host connected to switch. my pc and the VM on it, are two host connected to each other using a router.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have routing enabled on the host machine and disable if it is.